# How can I get List Category Posts to work as a widget?

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

This plugin works just fine in a post/page, but I need it to appear in a Text widget. Anyway to make it work in this location?

Answer (score 1):

to enable shortcode in textwidgets, add this to functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin includes a widget:

> It includes a widget which works pretty much the same as the plugin.
>   Just add as many widgets as you want, and select all the available
>   options from the Appearence > Widgets page.

After activating the plugin, you should find the widget "List Category Posts" in the Appearence > Widgets page and add it to your ["widgetized" theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets).